# Does diffraction change longitudinal component of k?

Tags: optics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Say a monochromatic wave in 2D travelling in the $x$ direction passes an aperture of width $a$ at $x=0$. The amplitude distribution in $k_y$ afterwards will follow the Fourier transform of the shape of the slit, i.e., that of a crenel function supported on $(-a/2, a/2)$: one would observe relative intensities proportional to $\mathop{\mathrm{sinc}} (k a \sin\alpha / 2)$ under angle $\alpha$ from the normal. The narrower the slit, the stronger the diffraction. It can be shown that the first interference minimum appears at $\alpha_1$ for which $\sin\alpha_1 = \lambda/a$, or
$$\Delta k_y = k\sin\alpha_1 = 2\pi/a.$$

A parallel can be made with the measurement-disturbance principle of quantum mechanics, applied on individual photons: the slit represents a binary measurement of $y$-component of position, so "after" the measurement (in $x > 0$) the originally sharp distribution of $p_y = \hbar k_y$ is blurred so that $\Delta y \Delta p_y \ge \hbar/2$.

However, in this analogy, the $p_x$ ($= \hbar k_x$) component had no reason to change. On the other hand, if $\vec k = (k, 0)$ changed to $\vec k' = (k, k\sin\alpha)$, a vector with a higher length, the frequency $\omega = |\vec k|c$ would have to increase, which to my best knowledge is not observed. Where is the error?

I can think of the following,

1. The vector changes to $\vec k' = (k\cos\alpha, k\sin\alpha)$. Then I'd like to hear what makes the $x$ component drop if the measurement was only made in $y$. Perhaps the $x$-extent of the slit – the *thickness* of the obstacle – plays some role (what, mathematically)?
2. The analogy is not correct because particles of light move at $c$ and can't be described using nonrelativistic QM. How about a matter wave then, would that change frequency?
3. I made some implicit assumption or approximation somewhere and then stepped out of its validity.
4. The analogy is flawed on a fundamental level, e.g., treating the region $x>0$ as the situation after a measurement.

Comment: Just as diffraction from a grating, the answer is the vector 'changes' - energy must be conserved. But, all those wavevectors were in the original plane wave anyway - the slit is just the transverse momentum filter. (And here is where one sees the direct connection to Hugen's wavelets).

Comment: @JonCuster Why is energy conserved although momentum is not? Also, how do waves with different $k_y$ form together my incident plane wave? I thought decomposition into a superposition of plane waves was unique, and my decomposition has only a single contribution from $(k,0)$.

Comment: They are, of course, both conserved for photons. Switch to the Huygen's analogy, and you see that for any wavelet origin with a non-zero $k_{y}$ there is another place that cancels that non-zero $k_{y}$ out _for the plane wave_. Once you remove that spot (it isn't in the slit), there is nothing to cancel it out. For a perfect plane wave you have all (energy allowed) $k_{y}$ present. (And this is why figuring out diffraction grating patterns is easiest in momentum space).

Comment: @JonCuster Ooh, I forgot about Huygens. That's smart. Care to answer?

Comment: I’ll try to find some time. But, this is my second week in a row with a 3-day meeting, so time is a little scarce...